# Are reviewers of edits notified of results?

Tags: support, suggested-edits

Are reviewers of edits notified of the results?

E.g. if one and only one reviewer rejects an edit-suggestion that is accepted, does this reviewer receive feedback on it?

The same question goes for all other outcomes.

Comment: Nope, such thing does not exist. Think there is feature request to add it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By design, no. A reviewer does not receive notifications about any suggested edit they've reviewed which was different (or same) as the community.

If you have a strong opinion about the edit, you can always choose to:

- Improve upon the suggested edit
- Reject the suggestion and edit yourself

---

As for having such a feature, I'd be strongly against it.

The users browsing the review queue generally go over about 40 posts. Even if they had different opinions on 5 of them, the notification inbox would get flooded, counting the number of comments/badges/other-messages they receive!

Comment: By default? Is there a setting?

Comment: @AdamJensen By _design_. English is not my native language.